# I purchase api for sms gateway I have implmented in php. when i execute in localhost it shows error?

Tags: php

I purchase api for sms gateway I have implemented in php. when i execute in localhost it shows error?they  have given the sample code and I have read the documentation and implemented but I don't how to rectify this error.
Process Failed, Please check your connecting domain, username or password.
Here is my php code:

```
<?php
$uid="obfuscated"; //your uid
$pin="obfuscated"; //your api pin
$sender="PSGRKC"; // approved sender id
$domain="http://www.smsalertbox.com/"; // connecting url 
$route="5";// 0-Normal,1-Priority
$method="POST";
if(isset($_REQUEST['send']))
{
    $mobile=$_REQUEST['mobile'];
    $message=$_REQUEST['message'];
    $uid=urlencode($uid);
    $pin=urlencode($pin);
    $sender=urlencode($sender);
    $message=urlencode($message);
    $parameters="uid=$uid&pin=$pin&sender=$sender&route=$route&mobile=$mobile&message=$message ";
    $url="http://$domain/api/sms.php";
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    if($method=="POST")
    {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$parameters);
    }
    else
    {
        $get_url=$url."?".$parameters;
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $get_url);
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,0);  // DO NOT RETURN HTTP HEADERS 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);  // RETURN THE CONTENTS OF THE CALL
    $return_val = curl_exec($ch);
    if($return_val=="")
    echo "Process Failed, Please check your connecting domain, username or password.";
    else
    echo "Message Id : $return_val"; //Returning the message id  :  Whenever you are sending an SMS our system will give a message id for each numbers, which can be saved into your database and in future by calling these message id's using correct API's you can update the delivery status.
}
echo "<form name='f1' method='post'>";
echo "<p> Mobile: <input name='mobile' > </p>";
echo "<p> Message: <textarea name='message' ></textarea> </p>";
echo "<p> <input type='submit' value='Send' name='send'></p>";
echo "</form";
?>
```

Comment: Process Failed, Please check your connecting domain, username or password.

Comment: Should you really be posting your $uid and $pin values publicly? You may wish to edit your post to hide them.

Comment: Also, you're missing a `>` on the last line: `echo "</form";`

Comment: `Please check your connecting domain` Should you be checking your code from the domain which you have registered with the paid service ?

Comment: thanks for your suggestion I want to know how to show the post $uid and  $pin  without publicly.what i have to do? what was the error at your end.same file If I push to server http://vkacademy.in/edu/ I got different error:You don't have permission to access /edu/ on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request. I don't understand how to solve this. is there is any error in coding? because the was given by the api provider, they don't support for technical wise. if you help me out .I can improve my knowledge

Comment: also I Have changed the connecting domain to purchased url. it shows same error.

Comment: It does not matter. It is all visible in revision history

Comment: i dont understand revision history

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php

    //Code using curl

    //API stands for Application Programming Integration which is widely used to integrate and enable interaction with other software, much in the same way as a user interface facilitates interaction between humans and computers. Our API codes can be easily integrated to any web or software application. 

    //Change your configurations here.
    //---------------------------------
    $uid="username"; //your uid
    $pin="your_pin"; //your api pin
    $sender="sender"; // approved sender id
    $domain="your_domain"; // connecting url 
    $route="0";// 0-Normal,1-Priority
    $method="POST";
    //---------------------------------

    if(isset($_REQUEST['send']))
    {

        $mobile=$_REQUEST['mobile'];

        $message=$_REQUEST['message'];

        $uid=urlencode($uid);
        $pin=urlencode($pin);
        $sender=urlencode($sender);
        $message=urlencode($message);

        $parameters="uid=$uid&pin=$pin&sender=$sender&route=$route&mobile=$mobile&message=$message ";

        $url="http://$domain/api/sms.php";

        $ch = curl_init($url);

        if($method=="POST")
        {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$parameters);
        }
        else
        {
            $get_url=$url."?".$parameters;

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $get_url);
        }

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,0);  // DO NOT RETURN HTTP HEADERS 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);  // RETURN THE CONTENTS OF THE CALL
        $return_val = curl_exec($ch);


        if($return_val=="") {
        echo "Process Failed, Please check your connecting domain, username or password.";
        } else {

        echo "Message Id :". $return_val; //Returning the message id  :  Whenever you are sending an SMS our system will give a message id for each numbers, which can be saved into your database and in future by calling these message id's using correct API's you can update the delivery status.

    }

    echo "<form name='f1' method='post'>";

    echo "<p> Mobile: <input name='mobile' > </p>";

    echo "<p> Message: <textarea name='message' ></textarea> </p>";

    echo "<p> <input type='submit' value='Send' name='send'></p>";

    echo "</form>";

    ?>
```

Comment: array('uid'=>$uid,'pin'=>$pin,'sender'=>$sender,'route'=>$route,'mobile'=>$mobile,'message'=>$message);
             $url='http://localhost/crul/smscode_curl.php';
       $ch = curl_init($url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($parameters));
             if($method=="POST")
            {
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, parameters);
            }

Comment: see the code i have done like that it shows Message Id :
Mobile: 

Message:

Comment: route 0 or 1 but why did you set it as 5

Comment: thanks for you reply , I am execute form local.i think no problem in thatI consult with the sms gateway person he told you can connect with any url.what i have done  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.psgrkc.com/');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); the error is Warning: curl_setopt(): supplied argument is not a valid cURL handle resource in E:\xampp\htdocs\crul\smscode_curl.php on line 61

Comment: This is transactional route so i have used route 5 that is clear.no problem in that i don't know why the message is not going.

Comment: yes if you can help me out it is very useful to me further i will do that in dynamic way like excel sheet upload or csv

Comment: i hope your user id and pin is correct and you have taken from APIs & Downloads -> settings

Comment: Have you added your ip in whitelist

Comment: no i have not done anything like that. will it useful for this code

Comment: And the url is not yours but api providers url

Comment: i just created an account in smsalert and gone through the settings

Comment: yes what you said is correct. my friend asked me to do this task now i have added my url ip. i got the message also. I have taken the api from smsalert box they given that api code also we can download.

Comment: I thing your are trying at your  end.I am waiting for you your answer.my sincere thanks for stack team and indra